# jQuery dropdown menu acting strange in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

If you look at this URL in IE (I'm using IE10 but it seems to do the same in older versions too).

[Demo link](http://newdemo4.virtual-showroom.com/)

When the sub options are open, the menu seems to close and open in a random fashion. EG: Our Services > Servicing & MOT. It only seems to happen on a few sub links, and it doesn't always trigger.

This is the jQuery code I'm using, which should only trigger on the first ul > li hover.

```
$('#mainNav ul:first>li').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).children('ul').css('top', '50px').css('left', '0px');
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown('fast');
  },
  function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp('fast', function(){
      $(this).children('ul').css('top', '-99999px').css('left', '-99999px');
    });
  }
```

Any idea why this is happening please?

Comment: Before I try to play with the code, I see that in Explorer when you are hover the "border" between <li> elements the hover is no more valid and the menu disappear. Let's try to put padding-top padding-bottom margin-top margin-botton to 0px then see if the issue remains. Then we can workaround on the border.

Comment: I think you've found the answer my friend. Getting rid of the margin stops it from happening. So it seems hovering over the margin area is triggering the hide/show events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment you have this in your CSS:

```
#mainNav ul ul li {
    background-image: url("../images/blocks/white-95.png");
    float: none;
    margin-top: 2px; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

try to change the margin to 0px and to set the border-top to 2px instead with a color you like. It might work.

Comment: Think you might be onto a winner..!!

Comment: Yep. Setting a border-top instead of a margin has sorted it. Thanks for your help.